# Is every multiplicative subgroup of $M_n(R)$ a subgroup of $GL_n(R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm afraid this turns out to be a really stupid question, but let's observe that the set of $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in a ring $R$ can contain groups that (1) don't necessarily share the same identity with $GL_n(R)$, and (2) are not included in $GL_n(R)$. For example, the trivial subgroup consisting of the zero matrix (together with matrix multiplication).

1. I was wondering whether every such "multiplicative" group of $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in a ring $R$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_n(R)$. In other words, does $GL_n(R)$ contain (an isomorphic copy of) every subgroup of $M_n(R)$? Again, by subgroup I mean a group that may **not** share the same identity element in $GL_n(R)$.
2. Would my question make more sense if "subgroup" was replaced with "finite subgroup"

Comment: You shouldn't use the word subgroup at all in this context, because "subgroup" has a standard meaning, and you can only have a subgroup of a group. Call it something else.

Comment: @DerekHolt This is standard terminology in monoid theory; a subgroup of a monoid $M$ can very well have a different identity element than that in $M$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $M_n(R)$, as described. Let $E$ be the identity of this group, to distinguish from the identity matrix $I$, which is a diagonal of $1$s (which I assume $R$ contains).

Clearly, $E$ is idempotent, as all identities are. Thus, $I - E$ is also idempotent, and moreover, given any $A \in G$, we have:
$$0 = A - A = A(I - E) = (I - E)A.$$
I claim that the map
$$\phi : G \to M_n(R) : A \mapsto A + I - E$$
is an injective homomorphism whose range is contained in $\operatorname{GL}_n(R)$. We have:
$$\phi(A)\phi(B) = AB + A(I - E) + (I - E)B + (I - E)^2 = AB + I - E = \phi(AB).$$
Clearly $\phi$ is also injective. From this, we conclude that the image of $\phi$ is a subgroup with identity $\phi(E) = E + I - E = I$. Thus, given any $A \in G$, and its inverse $A^{-1}$ in $G$ (i.e. so that $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = E$), we therefore have
$$\phi(A)\phi(A^{-1}) = \phi(AA^{-1}) = \phi(E) = I,$$
and $I = \phi(A^{-1})\phi(A)$ similarly, hence $\phi(A)$ and $\phi(A^{-1})$ are inverses in $M_n(R)$, hence $\phi(A) \in \operatorname{GL}_n(R)$. So, the image of $\phi$ is a subgroup of the group $\operatorname{GL}_n(R)$, with the usual identity, and $\phi$ becomes an isomorphism between this group and $G$.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful answer!

Comment: I suppose this proof does not need $R$ to be commutative?

Comment: @mathfan24 Indeed, I concur. However, I haven't done any ring theory since I was an undergrad, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: This same line of reasoning shows the claim holds for any ring with unit, not even restricted to matrix rings.

Comment: @SteveD I was thinking this, but did not have the confidence to say so. :)